# Number of ways to pick one or more elements from a set of $N$ elements

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm looking for a particular formula in combinatorics, but I don't even know what it would be called.   It is likely related to the [Bell Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Given a set of $N$ elements, I'd like to know how many different ways I can pick one-or-more elements from the set.

For example: $N = 3$  (set consisting of `a`, `b`, and `c`)

1. `a`
2. `b`
3. `c`
4. `a` + `b`
5. `a` + `c`
6. `b` + `c`
7. `a` + `b` + `c`

(The Bell Number for a set of size 3 is only 5, so it comes up short of what I'm looking for)

Is there a term for this value, and how can it be calculated?

Comment: $2^n - 1$? Its the size of the powerset minus one because you don't want the empty set.

Comment: So, you want all non empty subsets? There are $2^N-1$ of these :)

Comment: If $N$ is the same as the number of elements of the set you seem to just want the size of the power set minus one.

Comment: I specifically removed (set-theory) because it doesn't apply to this question; see its [tag info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/set-theory/info). Please don't add it back in.

Comment: That's not how this site works; tags are for what the question is _actually_ about, not what OP or any outsiders coming in _thinks_ it's about. A user got in [an edit war](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1145329/revisions) recently because he just _had_ to have the (set-theory) on his question and lost that battle (then threw a tantrum on meta and chat and got a long suspension). This is an even more clear-cut case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select one or more elements from a set, you are selecting a *non-empty* subset. So you are looking for a way to count the number of non-empty subsets of a set.

This is exactly the cardinality of the powerset of your set minus 1 (throw away the empty set). For a set of size $n$, its powerset has $2^n$ elements. Thus the number of ways of selecting one or more elements from a set of size $n$ is $2^n-1$.

You can also do this with combinations. Recall that ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is the number of ways of choosing $k$ objects from $n$ objects. Looking at it this way you have: $${n \choose 1} + {n \choose 2} + \cdots + {n \choose n} = -1 + {n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} + \cdots + {n \choose n} = -1 + (1+1)^n = 2^n-1$$
where I used the binomial theorem to get the next to last equality.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! What happens if the set of size n has repeating elements? I have asked a very similar question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493889/number-of-possible-subsets-of-all-sizes Thanks any help.

Answer (score 1):

$\binom{N}{1}+\binom{N}{2}+\cdots+\binom{N}{N}=2^N-1.$